# Find optimal algorithm to reach specific amount of coins in shortest time with cost of upgrading

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, data-structures

I think I met more likely a mathematical problem rather than a algorithm problem. The question description is as follow,

In a game there's a box that produces 2 coins per second. The goal is to reach A number of coins. It cost B number of coins to upgrade, after which the number of coins produced per second is increased by C, and player can upgrade unlimited number of times by paying B coins. Write code to give optimal upgrades and find shortest runtime for the solution in terms of A, B and C.

For example, it costs 6 coins to let the box produce 2 more coins per second, and the target is to reach 50 coins. How to determine the best upgrading timing? Appreciate it.

Comment: For low numbers, it can be definetly solved using reduction to shortest-path problem. I do believe there is more efficient solution, however.

Comment: I suspect a greedy approach that at the first of each days "asks" if it worths to upgrade the machine will work. Don't know how to prove it though.

Answer (score 2):

If we're going to pay for an upgrade, then we should do it as soon as possible. The `k`th upgrade thus takes `B/(2 + (k-1)*C)` seconds, making the pay rate `2 + k*C` coins per second. After we're done upgrading, we have to accumulate `A` coins with our top-of-the-line box. This takes `A/(2 + k*C)` seconds for a machine that has been upgraded `k` times.

The savings in completion times in going from `k-1` upgrades to `k` is thus

```
A/(2 + (k-1)*C) - A/(2 + k*C) - B/(2 + (k-1)*C) =
A*C/((2 + (k-1)*C) * (2 + k*C)) - B/(2 + (k-1)*C).
```

We care about the sign, so multiply through by the positive quantity `(2 + (k-1)*C) * (2 + k*C)`.

```
A*C - B*(2 + k*C) = -B*C*k + A*C - 2*B
```

As long as this quantity is positive, we should increase `k`. This implies that

```
k = floor((A*C - 2*B)/(B*C))
```

upgrades is the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you David, this is a nice solution.